# Is there a single word to mean the process of making someone angry by calling him angry?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the word that describes a situation similar to this:

A person is not angry and is minding his own business, but then someone comes up and starts annoying the person by repeatedly asking him if he is angry. Due to the constant annoying behaviour, the person who was not angry became angry.

Comment: @Rudra, Is this person doing it on purpose or are they just over-conscientious?

Comment: Yes, on purpose.

Comment: Hi Rudra, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: This sounds like a Monty Python sketch...

Comment: @Cascabel No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

[Baiting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/baiting):

> bait verb [ T ] (MAKE ANGRY) ​
>
> to intentionally make a person angry by saying or doing things to
>   annoy them:

Comment: What the OP is asking about may be a form of a baiting, in this sense, in so far as calling somebody angry may, in fact, annoy him, but it is only one of its forms. There is an aspect of a self-fulfilling prophecy in the phenomenon that the OP is asking about, and *baiting* does not capture that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **self-fulfilling prophecy**.

> In a self-fulfilling prophecy an individual’s expectations about another person or entity eventually result in the other person or entity acting in ways that confirm the expectations.

The term is sometimes over-generalized to many other situations, but the definition clearly indicates the situation presented here.

[Britanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/self-fulfilling-prophecy)

Answer (score 0):

In a broader sense, (inclusive of the specific scenario) the words ***instigate*** and ***provoke*** can be used to accurately describe this behavior. Both can be used to describe the act of eliciting a negative response.

"I was in a good mood until Bob *provoked* me to anger."

"Mary is a troublemaker -- she likes to *instigate* arguments, by spreading gossip."

Answer (score 0):

**Exasperate** seems to fit the bill quite nicely.

> To exasperate someone is to annoy him or her to the point of impatience, frustration and irritation, like when you exasperate a busy waiter by asking questions like "what are all the ingredients in the salad dressing?" and making him repeat the specials five times.

[Vocabulary.com]

Answer (score -1):

I think, "*to anger*" suits.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anger:

***anger***

transitive verb

: to make (someone) angry

// He was angered 
by the decision